# Spring Boot 2.4.5 and Java 11 of module system question

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In my example above I had spring.boot.starter.web on the classpath and the app failed to start. If I add org.apache.tomcat.embed.core then the application starts successfully.

When I configured module-info.java this way

```
requires spring.boot;
requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;
requires spring.web;
requires spring.boot.starter.web;

2021-05-20 10:56:09.501  INFO 17112 --- [           main] com.example.police.PoliceApplication     : Starting PoliceApplication using Java 11 on zhaozhiguang-pc with PID 17112 (D:\item\police\target\classes started by zhaozhiguang in D:\item\police)
2021-05-20 10:56:09.501  INFO 17112 --- [           main] com.example.police.PoliceApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-05-20 10:56:10.565  INFO 17112 --- [           main] com.example.police.PoliceApplication     : Started PoliceApplication in 1.435 seconds (JVM running for 3.153)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

My guess is that Tomcat didn't boot

or

```
requires spring.boot;
requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;
requires spring.web;
requires org.apache.tomcat.embed.core;
```

This one worked

```
2021-05-20 10:57:48.097  INFO 13740 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-05-20 10:57:48.334  INFO 13740 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2021-05-20 10:57:48.381  INFO 13740 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2021-05-20 10:57:48.396  INFO 13740 --- [           main] com.example.police.PoliceApplication     : Started PoliceApplication in 2.001 seconds (JVM running for 3.202)
2021-05-20 10:57:48.846  INFO 13740 --- [)-192.168.1.107] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-05-20 10:57:48.846  INFO 13740 --- [)-192.168.1.107] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-05-20 10:57:48.847  INFO 13740 --- [)-192.168.1.107] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
```

why?

spring.boot.starter.web depend on org.apache.tomcat.embed.core ?

Answer (score 3):

One of the main features of Spring Boot is *auto-configuration*, which means that it configures a feature if it's available.

However, with Java modules, "available" is not just determined by the jar being on the classpath, but also by access being granted with the `requires` statement.

Without the `requires` statement, Spring Boot's auto-configuration cannot see Tomcat, so it doesn't even attempt to configure it.

*Result:* Silently ignores that feature.

Comment: Thank you,So what do I need to do? I'll use other JAR or features as well,I may not know what went wrong, right.This add 'requires org.apache.tomcat.embed.core' is I found it somewhere else